# How to reduce Puppeteer launch and page and goto times on Cloud Functions?

Tags: time, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I deployed my webscraping function to Cloud Functions. When I run my script on local machine, the whole script takes about 6s to execute. When I run it on cloud functions, only to launch the browser takes minutes. The whole execution exceeds 9 minutes and Cloud functions just ends it after those 9 minutes. What can I do?

Here are the logs for times of execution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KlHl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDm6G.png)

I use these args to launch puppeteer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69V6A.png)

I use a puppeteer.cjs file to be even able to launch it in cloud functions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEJ01.png)

Comment: Do not post images of text. Read this [guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). None of your screenshots are useful in solving this problem. I would not even attempt to run Puppeteer in Cloud Functions. You might be successful with larger instance sizes of Cloud Run provided that you first test everything running in a container with Docker.